# Call application->run() again

Tags: symfony, console

We have a symfony 2 console command app. Inside a command (extending `\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command`) we call another command.

[Code:](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun/blob/master/src/N98/Magento/Command/System/Setup/RunCommand.php#L30)

```
$this->getApplication()->run(new StringInput('cache:flush'), new NullOutput());
```

This was working fine until the update to the recent Symfony version

But now I hit the exception in the following Symfony function (`\Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput::parseArgument()`)

```
private function parseArgument($token)
{
    $c = count($this->arguments);  ## $c is 0 !

    // if input is expecting another argument, add it
    if ($this->definition->hasArgument($c)) {
        $arg = $this->definition->getArgument($c);
        $this->arguments[$arg->getName()] = $arg->isArray()? array($token) : $token;

    // if last argument isArray(), append token to last argument
    } elseif ($this->definition->hasArgument($c - 1) && $this->definition->getArgument($c - 1)->isArray()) {
        $arg = $this->definition->getArgument($c - 1);
        $this->arguments[$arg->getName()][] = $token;

    // unexpected argument
    } else {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Too many arguments.');  ### this exception is thrown
    }
}
```

Both of the commands (the original one `dev:setup:run` and the one we call `cache:flush`) do not need parameters.

References: https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun/issues/90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This commit](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/5b19c892cff52d8d50bcd4b1397cff8972acb9df) causes Symfony2 to not behave like expected, as you can see in [the comments](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/5b19c892cff52d8d50bcd4b1397cff8972acb9df#commitcomment-2722373).

However, this change is reverted, but only in the Symfony2.2 branch (which is a mistake, I guess). You need to update your Console dependency to some 2.2.x version.
You can savely update to the 2.2.x version, because there are no BC breaks in the Console component (just some [really cool features](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-2-better-interaction-from-the-console))